# CSS - Change background image without affecting linear gradient?

Tags: css, sass

I have a div which is used to represent categories on a site.  The div is given a class which corresponds to the name of the category.

The div is first given a default background, using the following Sass mixin:

```
@mixin category-background($from, $to, $image) {
    background: linear-gradient(top, $from, $to), url(#{$image}) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Which I then call like this:

```
div.header {
    @include category-background(transparentize(#fff, $header-transparentize), transparentize(#fff, $header-transparentize), 'default.jpg');
}
```

If I have a specific background, I then call the mixin again with the correct image:

```
div.header.specfic-category {
    @include category-background(transparentize(#fff, $header-transparentize), transparentize(#fff, $header-transparentize), 'specific-image.jpg');
}
```

I'm concerned that when compiled, this could produce a lot of duplicate CSS.  Is there anyway to just replace the background image without affecting the gradient?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't specify them separately.

The [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) is used as an image, so you are actually specifying two background images for the element. When you specify multiple background images you have to specify them all at once, you can't have them in separate styles.

Answer (score 1):

If I think you're trying to achieve what I think, perhaps what you're looking for is `::before` and `::after` combination?

In this example I added gradient and changed png image (using `::before`) to darker on hover:

[image: button hover]